# Industrial standard communication between multiple micro controllers on same pcb

Tags: microcontroller, communication

I'm just wondering what would be considered industry practice of communicating between multiple micro controllers on the same pcb for instance when the digital i/o's or analog ins have been used.

Comment: How many microcontrollers?  What's the max data rate that you are expecting?

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous standardized link layer interfaces available - typically at least I2C, SPI, UART and parallel - but to the best of my knowledge there are no uniformly accepted standards for higher level protocol layers for inter-MCU comms. If you need to do it then you just roll your own to suit your particular requirements.